# OpenTBS removes spaces with formatted text in docx

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a docx file with formatted text. After merging a variable, the spaces disappear before and after formatted text in the result document.

This is the code I use from the example:

```
include_once('../tbs/tbs_class.php'); // Load the TinyButStrong template engine
include_once('../open_tbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php'); // Load the OpenTBS plugin

// prevent from a PHP configuration problem when using mktime() and date()
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.1.0')>=0) {
    if (ini_get('date.timezone')=='') {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    }
}

// Initialize the TBS instance
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong; // new instance of TBS
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN); // load the OpenTBS plugin

$template = 'test_template_word.docx';//select templatename
$project_name = 'Test name';
//load template
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8); // Also merge some [onload] automatic fields (depends of the type of document).
//$TBS->LoadTemplate($template,OPENTBS_ALREADY_XML); // Also merge some [onload] automatic fields (depends of the type of document).

$output_file_name = str_replace('.', '_'.date('Y-m-d').$save_as.'.', $template);

$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, $output_file_name); // Also merges all [onshow] automatic fields.
```

This is the ms-word template [test_template_word.docx](https://foei.eventacoustics.nl/elka32/open_tbs/test_template_word.docx)
What should I do to remain the original formatted text with the spaces?

This is the result file after merge: [test_template_word_2019-07-20.docx](https://foei.eventacoustics.nl/elka32/open_tbs/test_template_word_2019-07-20.docx)

Comment: Can you give an example of the TBS fields in the template and the data yu are merging, related with the problem ?

Comment: This is in the template file:
“[onshow.project_name]” werd **gehouden** op:

After merging the spaces around the bold word disappeared:
 “Test name” werd**gehouden**op:  

The original template is in the downloadlink above.

Comment: i cannot repoduce the [problem](https://ibb.co/LrQThBq), what is your OpenTBS version ?

Comment: I use TBS * version 3.11.0 for PHP 5 and 7 and openTBS  * version 1.9.12

Comment: Same as me. Can you send the result DOCX you've got ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort I have added a link to the result file to the original post.

Comment: Your file is displayed correctly with my Ms Word 2019, but with LibreOffice Writer I have the same probleme than you. Which software to you use for viewing the DOCX ?

Comment: You are right, thank you. I just tried on a computer with a recent ms word version and the document is displayed correctly, so I can move on. For this test I used libreoffice. Although the original template file is displayed correctly in libreoffice, this does not apply to the merged file.